# Phonegap: Connect two devices on WiFi and get them to communicate with each other

Tags: cordova, wifi, communication

I'm still a beginner. so i hope that you will not linch me for asking funny questions Maybe it is not really a phonegap question, but i think someone will know the answer for my question.

I want to make an app that send data / content from phone (android or ios) to another phone or to pc over wifi (they are on the same network). For example: Customer is choosing / ordering items on a phone and when he is done with ordering he sends order to the other person on pc / phone so the other person can see what the customer has ordered and then sends him back the notification of the received order, so the customer sees that his order is accepted and in progress.

What is the best way to get this thing work, is there any library that allows this communication or api? is it better that phone sends data to server and then pc/phone pulls data from server?

Regards, Miha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For communication between two devices you need sockets.

I use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcpserver.

The API you will find here: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html

It works very well, but takes some time to configure everything.