# cordova socket programming to communicate two android device

Tags: cordova, sockets, ionic-framework, tcp, udp

I have two cordova ionic apps, which needs to communicate using sockets. is there any solution or plugin in cordova, in which i can create one server application and other as client application to start communicate.
is there any solution or example that can resolve that issue.
any help will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx all for your response and help truly appreciated, i made it done with chrome tcp socket although i dont have info of peer devices i.e. IP of peer devices, for that i have to use three different cordova plugins to establish peer to peer communication.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily have to use a Cordova-based one, but feel free to take a look at [sockets-for-cordova](https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova). A popular one that isn't Cordova-based is but works with Cordova just fine is [Sockets.io](https://socket.io/socket-io-with-apache-cordova/)

Comment: thanks  there , i checked that , and one issue i am facing , is getting ip i.e. how the peer devices know each other ip to communicate.

Comment: @nadsh So you want devices directly to chat with eachother?

Comment: yes exactly, need to send and recieve info over wifi like it have in native android (wifi peer to peer)

Comment: @nadsh you still need sockets, take a look here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034174/phonegap-connect-two-devices-on-wifi-and-get-them-to-communicate-with-each-othe. I wouldn't use that plugin though, it hasn't been updated in 3 years

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes and No.

1. One mobile as socket server, the other as socket client(not in same LAN), without any other server.  No!  Because as you said in the comment, you don't know the ip address of the server mobile phone.(And in some countries, the ip address of 4G mobile phone is an internal LAN ip address)
2. Build your own socket.io server.  All clients connect thru the socket.io server.  But this is not what you want, so No, again!
3. Around 85% Yes.  Use a Free STUN server for a peer to peer connection.  In my previous Cordova App, I use 'easyrtc', which is a free audio/video chat api for peer to peer connection.  Why 85%?  Because a STUN server cannot guarantee a successful connection between 2 mobile phones, if, e.g. one of the mobile phone is behind a 'Super Firewall'!  You'll need a TURN server, something like no. 2 to guarantee 100% successful connectiom.  But I can't find any Free TURN server in the Internet.  This kind of technology is called WebRTC.  (Web Real Time Communication)

Comment: What if I only need to send the data from master device and other only listen to that device and read that info

Comment: what you called the 'master' device is actually the socket client, while the device listening is actually the socket server.  Same reason, you'll not be able to find the ip address of the socket server, even if you do, that ip address may be a private LAN address provided by the mobile operator in the user's country.(without any port forewording)  That's why we need a STUN server.  (I would suggest you google STUN, it'll explain how you can get the 'public' ip and port of a socket server when that server is behind a router, and you don't have any control over that router.

Comment: If you want to take a look at what you can do with WebRTC and socket.io, you can visit a web site developed by my student: https://thisapp.zephan.top developed using Cordova, you may also download the Android apk at https://thisapp.zephan.top/thisapp.apk    You can open the website using PC/Android chrome browser, or install the apk in Android.  By registering 2 ids, you are able to send text/voice message to yourself(socket.io), or you can establish voice over ip connection(i.e. voice call by WebRTC).  There are 2 ids created for testing purposes, they are test1/test2,  password: qwerty

Comment: ok i will check this, i searched about the cordova webserver, and node implementation in cordova , i found this plugin nodejs-mobile-cordova, i really dont know what this plugin actually does, is it for network listner as it have channels ..

Comment: same problem for ANY plugin/api without STUN server: you don't know the ip and port of the listening device when both devices are not in the same LAN.  I don't think you'll find any solution without STUN or similar technologies of STUN.